# How to close form and reload grid after submit in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I found many response about my question and do that correctly, but as somebodies have such problem, my problem does not solved. i.e. my form does not disappear after click on submit button.
I use this code: (I guess my problem is tiny but i can not solve it, Please help me)

```
$(function(){
$("#grid").jqGrid({
url:'example.php',
datatype: 'xml',
mtype: 'POST',
colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
colModel :[ 
  {name:'invid', index:'invid', width:55, align: 'center'}, 
  {name:'invdate', index:'invdate', width:90, align: 'center'}, 
  {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:80, align:'center',editable: true}, 
  {name:'tax', index:'tax', width:80, align:'center',editable: true}, 
  {name:'total', index:'total', width:80, align:'center'}, 
  {name:'note', index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} 
],
height: 'auto',
width: 'auto',
editurl: "edit.php",
pager: '#pager',
rowNum:10,
cellEdit: true,
cellsubmit: 'remote',
cellurl: 'edit.php',
ondblClickRow: function(id, status) {
    //var pageNumber = jQuery("#grid").getGridParam('rowNum');
    //jQuery("#grid").editGridRow(id);
    alert(id);
},
afterSubmitCell: function(response) {
    if(response.responseText == "ERROR")
        alert('Zekki');
},
beforeSubmitCell: function() {
    alert('before'); 

},
rowList:[10,20,30],
sortname: 'invid',
sortorder: 'asc',
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
caption: 'My first grid',
multiselect: true,
multikey: 'ctrlKey',
toolbar: [true,'bottom'],
loadComplete: function () {
    //alert("OK");
},
loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
          'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +
          'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
    alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
}
}).navGrid('#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true},
    {
        afterSubmit:processAddEdit,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
    }, 
    {
        afterSubmit:processAddEdit,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
    }, 
    {
        afterSubmit:processAddEdit,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true
    }).filterToolbar();
function processAddEdit(response, postdata) {
    alert("* "+response.responseText+" *");
}
    /*var pageNumber = jQuery("#grid").getGridParam('page');
    var rowNumber = jQuery("#grid").getGridParam('rowNum');
     */

});
```

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should return something from your afterSubmit call back function.

Something like:

```
function processAddEdit(response, postdata) {
    alert("* "+response.responseText+" *");
    if (everything_is_ok)
        return [true,"",new_id];
    else
        return [false,"Some error happened",null];
}
```

See [trirand wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing&s%5b%5d=formedit#events).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but tried closing the form manually, I'm sure this is not the best thing to do but it works anyway.

Try adding this to the code

```
function processAddEdit(response, postdata) {
   alert("* "+response.responseText+" *");
   $(".ui-icon-closethick").trigger('click');
}
```

It is better to evaluate whether there is no error before closing the form anyway.