# How to reload data from dataUrl : jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid, and added one subgrid inside it, which looks like as below,

[image]

As you can see,
Rows with columns having 11 and 13 are main grid rows

And every row has subgrid having interest, 
The Add Record element shows Add Pop up for Subgrid

Here is the code for subgrid looks like,

```
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
            $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
            jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                url:"shops?q=2&ShopID="+row_id,
                datatype: "xml",
                colNames: ['Interest'],
                colModel: [
                    //{name:"Id",index:"ShopID",width:80,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:false,size:40}}, //Shop ID not required
                    {name:"id",index:"id",editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{dataUrl:'shops?q=3&ShopID='+row_id},editrules:{required:true}}
                ],
                rowNum:10,
                pager: pager_id,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                scrollOffset: 0,
                sortname: 'num',
                sortorder: "asc",
                height: '100%',
                editurl:'shops?q=5&ShopID='+row_id
            });
            jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{edit:false,add:true,del:true})
        },
        subGridRowColapsed: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            // this function is called before removing the data
            //var subgrid_table_id;
            //subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
            //jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).remove();
        }
```

Once we add value from Pop Up it goes to Interest tab for respective row of main grid and that added value should be removed from pop up.

Currently value gets added successfully but it stays there in pop up, until we refresh the main form.

Is there any way to reload add pop up after submitting ?

Appreciate your time, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem could be solved if you would set HTTP header `"Cache-Control: private, max-age=0"` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885956/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269567/315935)) in the response of `dataUrl`. If you use ASP.NET I would recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935).

Alternatively you can use the option

```js
ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false }
```

(see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422410/315935)).

If all above will not help, you can use `ajaxSelectOptions.data` **as function** which would allow you sure send different values of `ShopID` parameter of `dataUrl`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240517/315935) for more details.

**UPDATED**: I would recommend you additionally to use `recreateForm: true` option of Add and Edit forms. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6128195/315935) an example of the usage.

Comment: Hi Oleg , Actually , unless i reload form i can't manipulate the dynamic pop up content  but jqGrid has  afterSubmit event where we can manipulate content there after submitting. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @pradeep: The goal of `afterSubmit` is to process some additional data from the server's response and make additional modification *in the grid data*. Example: you save the data and the server generate new Id, TimstampOfLastChange etc data which you save in the grid. I use typically `rowversion` which exist in every row of the table in the database. It allows my to implement optimistic concurrency. If I understand your problem correctly your problem is only because of caching of previous response from `dataUrl`. It is another case.

Comment: @pradeep: For example, the user can open some form for editing and then cancel editing. In the case the `afterSubmit` will **not be called**. Do you need make some modification of `dataUrl` in the case too? Or probably I didn't correctly understood your problem?

Comment: @pradeep: Additionally I would recommend you to use `recreateForm: true` option of Add and Edit forms. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6128195/315935) an example.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution,

Actually we can use afterSubmit event  ,

Solution can be found at two these links

[How to close form and reload grid after submit in jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544511/how-to-close-form-and-reload-grid-after-submit-in-jqgrid)

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-to-reload-edit-form-after-submit/

Thanks, Please comment if anybody need more explanation